# Nested Case Statements in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, sas, hiveql

Does anyone have an idea on why this code isn't working?

```
create table2 as
select
    *,
    1 as count,
    case
        when a=1 then
            case 
                when tx="A_L" then "L"
                when tx="B_A" then "A"
                when tx="C_E" then "E"
                when tx in ("E_V","D_M","H_O","I_D") then "Other"
                when tx="F_S" then "S"
                when tx="G_L" then "L"
            end 
        when b=1 then 
            case
                when tx="A_L" then "L"
                when tx="B_A" then "A"
                when tx="C_E" then "E"
            end
        else
            case
                when tx="A_L" then "L"
                when tx="B_A" then "A"
                when tx="C_E" then "E"
                when tx in ("D_M","E_V","F_S","H_O","I_D") then "Other"
                when tx="G_L" then "L"
            end
    end as tx1
from table1
```

Or is there a simpler way to do this? I'm writing this within a proc sql statement and pushing it to Hadoop (so it needs to be HiveQL compatible).

Comment: can you share the results from your log?  And how do you define 'not working' ?

Comment: I don't have `hive` on hand right now, but the `count` alias is suspicious (it might be a reserved word), single quotes are safer than double quotes, and a table alias with `*` (table1.*) are worth trying.

Comment: @RawFocus In SAS and on Hue, the code simply does not run. Does it all look fine to you?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'll try putting count in quotes but I think that part is working fine - the nested case statements seem to be the issue because when I greatly simplify them (I need them to be set up in this complex way to return null if a=1, and tx not in any of the ones listed, etc.), the query works

Answer (score 6):

Combine nested Case statements into one case statement using either AND or OR clause.This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of testing , this one is more readable.

```
create table2 as
select
    *,
    1 as count,
    case
        when a=1 and tx="A_L" then "L"
        when a=1 and tx="A_L" then "L"
        when a=1 and tx="B_A" then "A"
        when a=1 and tx="C_E" then "E"
        when a=1 and tx in ("E_V","D_M","H_O","I_D") then "Other"
        when a=1 and tx="F_S" then "S"
        when a=1 and tx="G_L" then "L"         
        when b=1 and tx="A_L" then "L"
        when b=1 and tx="B_A" then "A"
        when b=1 and tx="C_E" then "E"
        when a!=1 and b!=1 and tx="A_L" then "L"
        when a!=1 and b!=1 and tx="B_A" then "A"
        when a!=1 and b!=1 and tx="C_E" then "E"
        when a!=1 and b!=1 and tx in ("D_M","E_V","F_S","H_O","I_D") then "Other"
        when a!=1 and b!=1 and tx="G_L" then "L"        
    end as tx1
from table1
```